# Factory pattern, memory leak

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, factory, factory-pattern

I am reading Hodges book "More Coding in Delphi", section on Factory Pattern.
Trying to learn stuff. Broke down my code into small unit.
I use `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := True;` and fallowing code produces me a memory leak. Why does it occur and how do I fix it?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils;

type
  TGatewayTpe = (gtSwedbank, gtDNB);

type
  TBaseGateway = class

  end;

type
  TSwedbankGateway = class(TBaseGateway)
  end;

type
  TGatewayFunction = reference to function: TBaseGateway;

type
  TGatewayTypeAndFunction = record
    GatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
    GatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction;
  end;

type
  TGatewayFactory = class
  strict private
    class var FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList: TList<TGatewayTypeAndFunction>;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
    class procedure AddGateway(const AGatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
      const AGatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction);
  end;

implementation

class procedure TGatewayFactory.AddGateway(const AGatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
  const AGatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction);

var
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction: TGatewayTypeAndFunction;
begin
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction.GatewayType := AGatewayType;
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction.GatewayFunction := AGatewayFunction;

  FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList.Add(_GatewayTypeAndFunction);
end;

class constructor TGatewayFactory.Create;
begin
  FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList := TList<TGatewayTypeAndFunction>.Create;
end;

class destructor TGatewayFactory.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList);
end;

initialization
  TGatewayFactory.AddGateway(
    gtSwedbank, 
    function: TBaseGateway
    begin
      Result := TSwedbankGateway.Create;
    end
  );

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the new question, this one is just what we like here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a compiler defect. Defining an anonymous method in the initialization section of the unit appears to lead to that anonymous method not being finalized, and so leaked. In this case I would work around the issue by moving the code from the initialization section to the `class constructor`.

So, remove the `initialization` section completely, and change the class constructor to be like this:

```
class constructor TGatewayFactory.Create;
begin
  FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList := TList<TGatewayTypeAndFunction>.Create;
  AddGateway(
    gtSwedbank,
      function: TBaseGateway
      begin
        Result := TSwedbankGateway.Create;
      end
  );
end;
```

Here is the simplest reproduction that I can concoct:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

implementation

type
  TProc = reference to procedure;

var
  Foo: TProc;

initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  Foo := procedure begin end;

end.
```

When you include this unit in a project, the anonymous method is reported as being leaked.

But this variant does not report a leak:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

implementation

type
  TProc = reference to procedure;

var
  Foo: TProc;

procedure DoInit;
begin
  Foo := procedure begin end;
end;

initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  DoInit;

end.
```

The defect was fixed in XE8.